# What's the advised way to resume / pause a Codename One app with native implementation?

Tags: codenameone

I am developping a mobile Codename One app (targeting Android for now, iOS then) that uses advanced camera features. Thus I need to use the native interface and implementation.

During the app lifecycle there is a need to release the camera (eg when the user switches from my app to another) which refers to onPause() in the Android world and to initialize the camera back again (eg when the user starts or goes back to my app) which referst to onCreate() in the ANdroid world.

So far when "pausing" and "resuming" my app I've used CN1 `stop()` and `start()` method from the main class where there I call a method from the native interface. But if you read the [native GoogleMaps demo](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMaps/native/android/com/codename1/googlemaps/InternalNativeMapsImpl.java) you'll see that they directly use `onPause()` and `onResume()` in the native implementation after adding a `LifecycleListener` during initialization.

Consequently which approach should be used for my next projects involving native interfaces  ?

Any hint appreaciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this will probably apply to native implementations in other OS's I would just use `stop()`/`start()` and offer a method within my native implementation for pause/resume.

This will allow you to test that in the simulator, the more code you have on the Codename One side (as opposed to native) the easier it will be.